# How To Insert Data From Xml To Dataset.Xsd vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I created a dataset xsd called Dataset1.xsd,and xml schema called purchase.xml

purchase.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="DataSet1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="purchase">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="kode_purchase" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="date_purchase" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Dataset1.xsd:

### purchase      |

kode_purchase |
date_purchase |

And this is my code in form :

Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("purchase.xml")
dataset11.ReadXml(stream, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema)
MsgBox(dsParents11.purchase.Rows.Count) 
**Problem:
Why the value is always 0 ?**